# Scraping through on Wiki using "tr" and "td" with BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wiki

Total python3 beginner here. I can't seem to get just the name of of the colleges to print out.
the class is no where near the college names and i can't seem to narrow the find_all down to what i need. and print to a new csv file.  Any ideas?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


res= requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_League")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
colleges = soup.find_all("table", class_ = "wikitable sortable")

for college in colleges:
    first_level = college.find_all("tr")
    print(first_level)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `soup.select()` to utilize css selectors and be more precise:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res= requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_League")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

l = soup.select(".mw-parser-output > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(1) a")
for each in l:
    print(each.text)
```

Printed result:

```
Brown University
Columbia University
Cornell University
Dartmouth College
Harvard University
University of Pennsylvania
Princeton University
Yale University
```

To put a single column into csv:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([e.text for e in l]).to_csv("your_csv.csv") # This will include index
```

Comment: That's...well...Beautiful!

Comment: amazing. I had to look up the css rules on nth-of-type to understand how to use it exactly. your solution works great!

Comment: any ideas on how to print to csv?

Comment: @DelleIsDelle if you're thinking of a single column csv, all you need is to add `,` to the end of each line. Or you can use pandas as added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
colleges = soup.find_all("table", class_ = "wikitable sortable")
```

you are getting all the tables with this class (there are five), not getting all the colleges in the table. So you can do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res= requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_League")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

college_table = soup.find("table", class_ = "wikitable sortable")
colleges = college_table.find_all("tr")

for college in colleges:
    college_row = college.find('td')
    college_link = college.find('a')
    if college_link != None:
        college_name = college_link.text
        print(college_name)
```

**EDIT:** I added an if to discard the first line, that has the table header

Comment: any ideas on how to print to csv?

Comment: That is another question but you can get ideas from this: https://realpython.com/python-csv/#writing-csv-files-with-csv